# In App Billing - Monthly Subscription Version 3

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

I want to implement Monthly Subscriptions for my application to enable an Ad-free Version. I have implemented a demo for that, and is working fine.

While implementing in real scenario in my application, I have a few queries :-

- What if a user changes his/her mobile device. How it can be managed at other device also. (I had planned when the subscription is purchased on one device, then save a Yes/No Value in shared pref and Enable or Disable the ads based on that. My problem is when I change the device, how the value of shared pref can be checked at other device)
- What if a user cancels the subscriptions from his Google Wallet. I have already saved Yes/No Value in the Preferences, for this I will check the active subscription using Purchase Status API. (Is this fine ?)

  **I just want to know a way how these subscriptions should be handled to enable a No-Ads Version for the application.
  Any Better suggestion is requested.**

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to pass the purchase data to your server which will store it at its end. You can fetch a users subscription status any time from your server. Simply check if shared pref has subscription info to show/hide ads. if shared pref doesn't have any subscription related data (either device change or user may have cleared the cache) you should ask your server for its data and show/hide ads accordingly.
2. If user cancels its subscription you can fire a inventory query which will give you the current status of purchase. So your approach would work here fine.